# How can I create a Python list with multiple of the same randomized element?

Tags: python, list, integer

The title does a poor job of explaining what I'm trying to do, but I essentially want to create a list in Python that is weighted by the number of times it shows up in the list for certain randomized elements. Once the element is selected by weight, it rolls the randomization after.

Example: `[3, 5, 6, 104, 108, 103]` where the code for this list makeup would be something like `[random.randint(1,10)]*3 + [random.randint(100,110)]*3`. As it stands now, something like `[random.randint(1,10)]*3` will always form a list of the same integer three times.

How can I form a list that has the three elements, but each element is it's own instance of the randomization function?

Comment: It seems like you should be using `random.choices` rather `random.randint`. Then you can you can get three numbers with : `random.choices(range(1, 10), k=3)`. Choices also takes a weights parameter, which might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use comprehensions:

```
[random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(3)] + [random.randint(100,110) for _ in range(3)]
```

`[random.randint(1,10)]` creates a list object and `* 3` just repeats that object 3 times.

`[x for _ in range(3)]` actually evaluates the expression `x` 3 separate times.

Comment: a question related, is there a difference between adding two such lists vs a list comp of range 6?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Adding lists is usually more expensive than creating a single list once.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Is there an easier way to create a weighted list of randomized elements rather than adding lists together?